# Tomcat , Websphere MQ and Atomikos : Not able to integrate transaction manager

Tags: tomcat, ibm-mq, mq, atomikos

Steps taken :

1. Followed all the steps which mentioned in the link 
   http://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/Tomcat7Integration35
   a. Copied "atomikos-integration-extension-3.7.1-20120529.jar" into TOMCAT_HOME/lib folder.

   b. server.xml

   c.  context.xml

   d. Added all the required transaction jars. Also transaction properties:
2. Changes done in the code ,

a. transaction.xml :

```
<bean id="UserTransactionBean"
    class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/UserTransaction"></property>
</bean>

<!--  One Bean that applies Transaction semantics as well as Retry Logic. It only supports
PROPOGATION_REQUIRED SEMANTICS.
-->
<bean id="TstTransactionInterceptor"
    class="com.test.transaction.interceptor.TstTransactionInterceptor">

    <property name="exceptionHandler" ref="TstRuntimeExceptionHandler" />

    <!--  Max Times to Retry a Transaction eligible for Retry -->
    <property name="maxRetryAttempts" value="1" />

    <!--  Time to wait between retries of eligible transactions ( in seconds)
    -->
    <property name="waitTimeBetweenRetries" value="2"></property>
    <property name="userTransaction" ref="UserTransactionBean" />

    <!--  List of methods that transaction interceptor will not apply declarative transactions for
    -->
    <property name="excludedMethodList">
        <list>
            <value>toString</value>
            <value>equals</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="JTATxManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="autodetectTransactionManager" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="SpringTransactionInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor">
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref bean="JTATxManager" />
    </property>
    <property name="transactionAttributeSource">
        <ref bean="TransactionAttributes" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

ISSUE:
We always get No JTA TransactionManager found in the logs only when we try to push a message to the queue. We are able to do DB calls successfully:

```
-- checkUserTransactionAndTransactionManager, No JTA TransactionManager found: transaction suspension not available

-- WARNING: atomikos connection pool 'QCF_MQSeries_XA_RMI': error creating proxy of connection atomikos pooled connection for resource QCF_MQSeries_XA_RMI
    [3/28/14 14:26:25:052 CDT] 00000137 ConnectionPoo W com.atomikos.logging.JULLogger logWarning atomikos connection pool 'QCF_MQSeries_XA_RMI': error creating proxy of connection atomikos pooled connection for resource QCF_MQSeries_XA_RMI
                             com.atomikos.datasource.pool.CreateConnectionException: atomikos pooled connection for resource QCF_MQSeries_XA_RMI: connection is erroneous

--  WARN   logWarning, atomikos MessageConsumer proxy for com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueReceiver@73085060: The JMS session you are using requires a JTA transaction context for the calling thread and none was found.
    WARN   logWarning, Error in proxy
    com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosTransactionRequiredJMSException: The JMS session you are using requires a JTA transaction context for the calling thread and none was found.
    Please correct your code to do one of the following: 
    1. start a JTA transaction if you want your JMS operations to be subject to JTA commit/rollback, or
    2. increase the maxPoolSize of the AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean to avoid transaction timeout while waiting for a connection, or
    3. create a non-transacted session and do session acknowledgment yourself, or
    4. set localTransactionMode to true so connection-level commit/rollback are enabled.
        at com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosTransactionRequiredJMSException.throwAtomikosTransactionRequiredJMSException(AtomikosTransactionRequiredJMSException.java:40)
```

If anybody has faced this issue , please let us know how you solved it.

Comment: Done this in the past and it surely works. I remember that different Tomcat/WMQ/Atomikos versions might have small differences in the JNDI setup though.

Do you get JTA transactions through with the database - or just get the database connection working? I would study the atomikos log to verify that DB is working with atomikos. 

Another pointer is to wire up the WebSphere MQ XAConnectionFactory using a spring bean directly - injecting the transaction manager, and when you have that working for sure - go back to JNDI config of WMQ.

Also, verify the startup log - DEBUG mode, for more pointers.

Comment: What version of WMQ client?  The XA client was not provided in the free client installer until recent versions of v7.0 and higher.  But even then, it was necessary to download the client again to get the XA capabilities. If the WMQ client is installed correctly, yuo can do `dspmqver` to determine which version.